# Multiplying a string by zero

Tags: python, string, computer-science

In terms of computer science, and specifically in Python, how to explain that multiplying a string by zero (which is an int) produces an empty string?

```
>>> 'hello' * 0
>>> ''
```

Comment: You can explain it as string composed of repeated contents of `'hello'` of length `len('hello') * 0`. The only string that matches this definition is `''` :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Follow the sequence:

```
'hello' * 3 == 'hellohellohello'
'hello' * 2 == 'hellohello'
'hello' * 1 == 'hello'
'hello' * 0 == ?
```

An empty string is the only thing that continues the sequence, so it's either that or undefined. It makes sense as "zero repetitions of the string `'hello'`".

This sequence is a way of looking for an inductive definition of string multiplication. We want to define that `s * (n + 1) == (s * n) + s`, and of course we want to define `s * 1 == s`. So when `n == 0` the only value that makes sense for `s * 0` is the empty string.

Mathematically, it's because the empty string `''` is the additive identity. The distributivity property of multiplication is that for any string `s` and non-negative integers `a`, `b`:

```
s * (a + b) == s * a + s * b
```

Putting `b == 0`, we see that:

```
s * a == s * a + s * 0
```

Hence string multiplication wouldn't be distributive over integer addition unless `s * 0` is the identity value of string addition.

Of course, there's no requirement that just because we call two operators "multiplication" and "addition" then they must be distributive. And in fact string multiplication in Python isn't distributive anyway as soon as negative numbers are involved. But to exclude `0` too by defining `s * 0` as anything else would be rather counter-intuitive.

Comment: It's that "undefined" that led me to post my question. I need a more "absolute" answer.

Comment: @palindrome: what do you mean? If GvR had chosen to define that `'hello' * 0` has no result, and instead throws an exception, then that would be so. There is no "absolute" answer, Python was invented by a person.

Comment: +1 I was busy writing my answer based on multiplication distributing over addition. And then when I submitted and got round to updating yours, I see that you had preceded me somewhat. I just wanted you to know that I didn't copy you!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: no worries, I didn't think you did. Based on your past answers I'm confident you have better things to do with your time than copy people :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: actually, I did fully understood Steves' answer just after reading yours. Thanks for both of you ;-)

Comment: Since anything multiplied by 0 is zero, and a sequence of zero items is an empty type, and `''` is an empty string, and string is just another sequence, then it makes sense :) What would be dubious is things like `'hello' * -2` doing "stuff"

Comment: @JonClements: perhaps unfortunately, `'hello' * -2` is defined in Python, and of course `'hello' * (-1 + 1) != 'hello' * -1 + 'hello' * 1`, so this doesn't fit either with an inductive definition of string multiplication as repeated addition or as a distributive module operator. If I had to, I'd guess that allowing multiplication by negative integers sort of fits with the philosophy that permits out-of-bounds slices.

Comment: From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations): A **negative** repetition factor yields an empty sequence.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I know... obviously `'hello'` * -2 should be `'olleholleh'` though... (you do know I'm being tongue in cheek here guys, right!?)

Comment: @JonClements: Nah, clearly `'hello' * -2` should be 10 backspace characters!

Answer (score 6):

The `*` operator is multiplication, the `+` operator is addition. For numeric types, we would typically expect `n*s` to be equal to `s+s+s+...+s` where there are `n` copies of `s` in the summation. This illustrates the typical relation between multiplication and addition.

We might expect that multiplication was distributive over addition. That is:

```
n*s + m*s == (n+m)*s
```

Now, suppose that `m` is zero. Then this the distributive rule yields:

```
n*s + 0*s == (n+0)*x == n*s
```

And consequently it is clear that `0*s` is the additive identity.

For a string, the addition operator is concatenation. And the identity for string concatenation is the empty string. From which we can conclude that `0*s` should be defined to be the empty string.